# how to access value of querystring parameters separated by '&amp;' ?,sent from a '.xsl' file to '.php' file

Tags: jquery, url

here is my code in '.xsl' file . from which i call to php file (using 'strurl' in code ).
and in php file , i get error while accessing value of querystring parameter 'action' i.e.
for bellow line-
$v=$_GET['action'];
and error is 'Undefined Index : action'

*******we need to write "& amp;" instead of '&' in url in '.xsl' file***************

```
var strurl="?errorcode=error"+"&amp;"+"action=error"+"&amp;"+"to=support@talentserv.co.in"+"&amp;"+"body="+data+"&amp;"+"subject=issue";


alert(strurl);
jQuery.ajax({      
    type:"GET",
    dataType: "text",
    url:strurl,
    success:function(data) {
        var data=data.toString();
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

so can anyone please tell me whats wrong???

Comment: UPDATE - we need to write '&amp;' instead of '&' in url in '.xsl' file

Comment: NO SPACE BETWEEN '&' and 'amp;'.